# Obtain mouse position in OCTAVE

Tags: mouseevent, octave

I am using OCTAVE on my PC for image processing and display.  I am reading in a .pgl file and converting it from rgb to gray to obtain a simple 2D array.  I then display this using imagesc().  What I'd like to do is use the mouse to click on a particular part of the image and return where the mouse was clicked in the array ((x,y) coordinates).  I've tried using ginput() which I think should work if I understand the documentation correctly.  But I can't get it to work.  Usually I have to control C out once I type in [x,y] = ginput(1), for example, because the prompt never returns in my input window no matter how many mouse clicks I do in the display (or returns in the input window - I have to control C out).  First is this do-able?  or am I attempting something OCTAVE just can't do?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

This should work with ginput and the FLTK toolkit. What version of Octave are you using on which OS? To make sure you are using FLTK toolkit use

```
close all
graphics_toolkit fltk
```

at the beginning of your script.

Comment: Admittedly, I'm using an old version of OCTAVE.  Version 3.2.4.  I'm running on windows, so I think its using some kind of a Cygwin intermediate step, but that's not obvious to me when I run it.  I'll take some time and upgrade to the latest version I can get for windows.  I tried the graphics_toolkit fltk command and my version didn't recognize the command "graphics_toolkit"

Comment: Yes 3.2.4 is really old. I suggest using the 3.8.2-5 MXE build from http://mxeoctave.osuv.de/

Answer (score 0):

The thing to remember with ginput() is that after clicking with the mouse in the plot window, you have to hit return key on the keyboard if the n parameter is not stated. After the return, the coordinates will be returned in the x,y vars. Also the button used to click will be returned when called with [x,y,buttons]=ginput(n). The 'n' argument controls the number of clicks to watch for before recording the coords. Works well in Octave 4.0.1.